# Unable to upgrade after installing Buster libidn.so.11

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Most of the troubleshooting and fixes can be found on the raspberrypi forums here:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=246039&p=1503013#p1503013

We're able to clean up apt-get update, now only apt-get uprade, dist-upgrade, et el, results in errors.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up triggerhappy (0.5.0-1) ...
/bin/systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on triggerhappy.service: No such file or directory
/bin/systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on triggerhappy.socket: No such file or directory
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/sbin/runlevel: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript triggerhappy, action "start" failed.
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package triggerhappy (--configure):
 installed triggerhappy package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 triggerhappy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

We're asking the 'big guns' to weigh in on this, as we've nearly exhausted everything else.

Comment: Do you installed [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) from that image and then do `sudo apt-get upgrade`? That is known to work.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-get update`? What do you mean you managed to "clean it up"?